# Angular 2 AoT rollup moment locale

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular2-aot, rollupjs

Does anybody know how apply a moment.js locale with AoT and rollup? 
In systemjs.config.js defined moment-with-locales.js doesn't work with:

```js
 //in systemjs.config.js.

'moment': 'npm:moment/min/moment-with-locales.js',

//in component:
import moment from 'moment';

this.moment.locale('de');
let formattedDate = this.moment(value).format('L');
```

and gives the default result in 'en'.

In the rollup-config.js:

```js
plugins: [
        nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
        commonjs({
            include: [
                'node_modules/rxjs/**',
                'node_modules/moment/min/**',
            ]
        }),
        uglify()
    ]
```

Comment: Did you find the solution ?